# C pointer refuses to reassign

Tags: c, pointers, avl-tree

I am writing an AVL tree in C, with each node keeping record of both its height and balance factor. I’ve encountered on odd bug when performing rotations. My rebalance function climbs the tree until it finds the root node or an unbalanced node, then checks the balance factors to figure out which rotations it needs to perform. The rotation functions take in double pointers and reassign the dereferenced node they were given. However, that didn’t seem to work, so for good measure I also made the functions return the node that took the original node’s place. This doesn’t seem to work either, which I don’t understand. On lines 164 and 171, I’m explicitly assigning the node’s child to the rotation function’s return value (which is what its new node will be.)

My rotation functions:

```
Node *rotateRight(Node **root) {
    Node *node = *root;
    Node *pivot = node->left; //pivot will become the new root
    if(node->parent) {
        Node *g = node->parent;
        pivot->parent = node->parent;
        if(pivot->datum < g->datum) g->left = pivot;
        else g->right = pivot;
    } else
        pivot->parent = NULL;
    node->parent = node->left;
    node->left = pivot->right? pivot->right : NULL;
    pivot->right = node;
    *root = node->parent;
    return pivot;
}

Node *rotateLeft(Node **root) {
    Node *node = *root;
    Node *pivot = node->right;
    if(node->parent) {
        Node *g = node->parent;
        pivot->parent = node->parent;
        if(pivot->datum < g->datum) g->left = pivot;
        else g->right = pivot;
    } else
        pivot->parent = NULL;
    node->parent = pivot;
    node->right = pivot->left? pivot->left : NULL;
    pivot->left = node;
    *root = node->parent;
    return pivot;
}
```

My rebalance function (retrace just finds the root of the tree):

```
Node *rebalance(Node **node) {
    if(-1 <= (*node)->bal && (*node)->bal <= 1) { //current node is balanced, we can ascend and check the next node
        if((*node)->parent) rebalance(&((*node)->parent));
        return retrace(*node);
    }
    if((*node)->bal == 2) {
        if((*node)->left->bal == 1) { //left left
            puts("ll");
            rotateRight(node);
            return retrace(*node);
        } else { //left right
            puts("lr");
            (*node)->left = rotateLeft(&((*node)->left));
            rotateRight(node);
            return retrace(*node);
        }
    } else {
        if((*node)->right->bal == 1) { //right left
            puts("rl");
            (*node)->right = rotateRight(&((*node)->right));
            rotateLeft(node);
            return retrace(*node);
        } else { //right right
            puts("rr");
            rotateLeft(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way to isolate problems here is to use a unit testing system to define simple test cases and ensure that the functions you're using actually do what's advertised under the different scenarios they're expected to handle. This is just a chunk of code, no explanation, so it's a debugging problem. If you had a specific test failure you'd have a specific problem to investigate.

Comment: `Node *rebalance(Node **node)` does not `return`a value on some paths (see `//right right`).  Save time: Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Why did you  not post the definition of `Node` and `retrace()`?

Comment: "However, that didn’t seem to work" --> There is no `main()` to call `rebalance()`.  Post lacks a [MCVE],